# CRM - MYSQL unir dos tablas y traer solo el registro con la fecha mas reciente de la segunda tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

`comercio_ficha` es la tabla que contiene cada oportunidad de venta, tiene su `comercio_id`

Tengo en una segunda tabla `nota_ficha` que contiene todas las notas añadidas por los comerciales a ese `comercio_ficha`, en la tabla `nota_ficha` esta el `comercio_id`.

Bien, para montar la portada de CRM quiero traerme el campo `nota_nota` mas actual de `nota_ficha` para cada uno de los `comercio_id` usando `nota_fechain`

pensé que sería fácil...

```
select comercio_ficha.*, nota_ficha.nota_nota
from comercio_ficha
left JOIN nota_ficha on comercio_ficha.comercio_id=nota_ficha.comercio_id
where nota_ficha.nota_id in 
    (select DISTINCT (comercio_id), nota_fechain
    FROM
    nota_ficha
    GROUP BY comercio_id, nota_fechain
    ORDER BY nota_fechain)

error 
[Err] 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

> where nota_ficha.nota_id in
>      (select DISTINCT (comercio_id), nota_fechain

en el where le estás diciendo que el Id de 'nota' sea cada distinto Id de 'comercio' **Y** la 'fecha'. El Id de 'nota' no puede ser dos cosas.

Prueba algo como

```
select x.*,y.nota_nota
from comercio_ficha x
left join nota_ficha y on x.comercio_id=y.comercio_id
where y.nota_fechain=(select max(z.nota_fechain)
                      from nota_ficha z
                      where z.comercio_id=y.comercio_id)
```

Comment: select comercio_ficha.*,nota_ficha.nota_nota
from comercio_ficha nota_ficha
left join nota_ficha comercio_ficha on comercio_ficha.comercio_id=nota_ficha.comercio_id
where nota_ficha.nota_fechain=(select max(nota_ficha.nota_fechain)
                      from nota_ficha comercio_ficha
                      where comercio_ficha.comercio_id=nota_ficha.comercio_id)

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'nota_ficha.nota_nota' in 'field list'

Comment: No entiendo este comentario, @krl, ¿qué es? ¿Has intentado poner la consulta sin los alias? Entonces sería algo como:
select comercio_ficha.*,nota_ficha.nota_nota
 from comercio_ficha
 left join nota_ficha
  on comercio_ficha.comercio_id=nota_ficha.comercio_id
 where nota_ficha.nota_fechain=(select max(nota_ficha.nota_fechain) from nota_ficha where nota_ficha.comercio_id=comercio_ficha.comercio_id).
Pero te recomiendo encarecidamente que empieces a usar alias.

Comment: tienes razón... en cualquier caso he puesto tu consulta en navicat y despues de 325 segundos la he parado pq no acababa... comercio_ficha tiene 35.597 registros y contacto_ficha tiene 25.231 registros.

Comment: Entonces, te recomiendo que des más detalles sobre tu base de datos y sobre las tablas, porque esa consulta con ese número de registros no debería dar esos problemas. ¿La consulta que has probado es la que usa alias o la que no los usa?

Answer (score 0):

Si solo quieres ese campo en especifico de la tabla nota_ficha puedes traerlo con una subconsulta utilizando order by y limit 1 de la siguiente manera.

```sql
 select comercio_ficha.*, 
      (select n.nota_nota 
       from nota_ficha n 
       where n.comercio_id=c.comercio_id
       order by n.nota_fechain desc
       limit 1) nota_nota
 from comercio_ficha c
```

De esta manera la subconsulta te ordenara las notas de la mas recienta a la mas antigua y el limit 1 hará que se seleccione solo la primera osea la mas reciente.

Adicional debes recordar que cuando utilizas una subconsulta en los campos a obtener esta debe traer solo un valor al igual que cuando la utilizas en una condición con operadores "=" o "<>" y cuando utilizas una subconsulta en una condición con el operador "in" o "not in" debe traer solo un campo osea puede traer multiples valores pero todos del mis campo.

Comment: entiendo que sería así como propones... imagino que "n" y "c" es economía del lenguaje...

 select comercio_ficha.*, 
      (select nota_ficha.nota_nota 
       from nota_ficha  
       where nota_ficha.comercio_id=comercio_ficha.comercio_id
       order by nota_ficha.nota_fechain desc
       limit 1) nota_nota
 from comercio_ficha 

despues de 140 segundos he parado la consulta, no chuta.

Comment: Aproximadamente, ¿cuántos registros tienes en las tablas?

Comment: comercio_ficha tiene 35.597 registros y contacto_ficha tiene 25.231 registros

Comment: ambas tablas están debidamente indexadas? con sus clave primarias y clave foráneas?